# How do I display Y values above the bars in a matplotlib barchart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am generating a bar chart from a dataframe, I want to remove the Y axis labels and display them above the bars. How can I achieve this?
This is my code so far:

```
ax = rounded_df.plot(kind='bar',
                     figsize=(20, 8),
                     width=0.8,
                     color=['#5cb85c', '#5bc0de', '#d9534f']
                     )
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.legend(fontsize=14)
plt.title('Percentage of Respodents\' Interest in Data Science Areas', fontsize=16)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

Here is my graph as it stands:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZq4K.png)

And here is the data:

```
                            Very_interested Somewhat_interested Not_interested
Data_Analysis/Statistics    72.95           21.36               3.31
Machine_Learning            75.59           19.88               2.69
Data_Visualization          60.01           32.87               4.57
Big_Data_(Spark/Hadoop)     59.65           32.65               5.69
Deep_Learning               56.56           34.48               6.09
Data_Journalism             19.21           48.41               27.32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `ax.patches` you can achieve it.

This will do:

```
for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005),color='green')
```

**Try:**

**sample data:**

```
    1q1         1q2         1q3         1q4
Cust / Month                
AA  62264.65    103189.45   94989.70    86212.37
AB  3330.47     0.00        0.00        0.00
AC  36580.00    36113.10    37527.84    32241.18
AD  36803.13    0.00        0.00        0.00
AE  44200.66    0.00        0.00        0.00
AF  12971.52    13697.76    13257.60    11931.84
```

**Sample Code:**

```
customer_count = [38.00, 30.00, 30.00, 20.00]

ax = res.T.plot(width=0.8, kind='bar',y=['Quarter Total'],figsize=(10,5))
for rect, value in zip(ax.patches, customer_count):
    if value != 0:
        h = rect.get_height() /2.
        w = rect.get_width() /2.
        x, y = rect.get_xy()
        ax.text(x+w, y+h,value, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', color='white',rotation=0)

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005),color='green')
    
plt.title('expediture data Quarter Wise')
```

---

[image]

---

---

**df:**

```
    a   b   c   d
a1  66  92  98  17
a2  83  57  86  97
a3  96  47  73  32
```

---

```
ax = df.T.plot(width=0.8, kind='bar',y=df.columns,figsize=(10,5))
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005),color='green')
  
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

---

[image]

Comment: How do I apply this method to my data set given that there are multiple columns? And is it possible to remove the Y axis from the graph?

Comment: can you post your dataframe in form of text?

Comment: see the edited post. If this helps close the question by accepting an answer by clicking on the tick mark. If doesn't let me know.

Comment: I am unsure how to correctly format it to make it tidy like yours.